# Override language detection in PyCharm editor?

Tags: javascript, html, pycharm

I'm building Jinja templates, most of which are HTML with a single Javascript section; the Javascript is reliably in a block named "script", e.g.:

```
{% block script %}
var foo = 'bar';
{% endblock %}
```

But when I do that, I don't get the nice Javascript syntax highlighting that I normally get inside  tags in regular HTML files.

Is there any way to add a regex or two to the PyCharm editor such that it will give me the proper syntax highlighting inside these script blocks?

Comment: I will note that adding "<script>" immediately before the opening block tag seems to cause highlighting to be proper and also does not cause any change in the rendering of the template.... However it is gross.

Comment: Looks like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-4598.

Comment: Similar, but a more restricted question and which might have a very different (and easier) answer. Still hoping....

Comment: PyCharm's parsing is implemented as Java code and does not use regular expressions. The only way to customize it is by writing a plugin.

Comment: If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.